# How to detect if a site supports HTTP/2 in PHP

Tags: php, https, http-headers, http2

Is there a simple way in PHP to test if a URL supports HTTP/2? I tried checking for connection upgrade or h2 in `curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HEADER, true)` as per [HTTP/2 identification in the specs](http://httpwg.org/specs/rfc7540.html#versioning) . There are many sites where you can add a URL and it will tell if the site supports HTTP/2 or not. Just wondering how they are testing it and if something similar can be done in PHP. On command line I can do something like `$ curl -vso --http2 https://www.example.com/`

Answer (score 20, accepted):

**Update 2021-02-25**: 
As [mentioned](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47357483/how-to-detect-if-a-site-supports-http-2-in-php/47411708#comment117299193_47411708) by [djdance](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2233069/djdance), `HTTP/2.0` has been `HTTP/2` for some time now. Therefore, you should really check against `HTTP/2` (and `HTTP/3` for the upcoming HTTP 3).

If you do not want to use `strpos`, you can now also use [`str_starts_with($response, "HTTP/2")`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.str-starts-with.php) when using PHP 8. Otherwise you can use `substr($response, 0, 6) === "HTTP/2"` for PHP 7.

For PHP 7.3 and cURL 7.50.0, `curl_getinfo` now also supports `CURLINFO_HTTP_VERSION`:

```
echo curl_getinfo($ch, CURLINFO_HTTP_VERSION);
// 3 for HTTP/2
```

The values which may be returned by `CURLINFO_HTTP_VERSION` (as of PHP 7.3):

```
CURL_HTTP_VERSION_NONE              === 0
CURL_HTTP_VERSION_1_0               === 1
CURL_HTTP_VERSION_1_1               === 2
CURL_HTTP_VERSION_2                 === 3
CURL_HTTP_VERSION_2_0               === 3
CURL_HTTP_VERSION_2TLS              === 4
CURL_HTTP_VERSION_2_PRIOR_KNOWLEDGE === 5
```

This means you can check for a specific (e.g., `CURL_HTTP_VERSION_2TLS`, which is HTTP/2 over TLS):

```
if (
    $response !== false
    && curl_getinfo($ch, CURLINFO_HTTP_VERSION) === CURL_HTTP_VERSION_2TLS
) {
    // The connection was established using HTTP/2 over TLS
    // if the server does not support TLS HTTP/1.1 will be used.
}
```

---

**Original:** 
Both your server and your installation of cURL need to support HTTP/2.0. After that you can just make a normal cURL request and add the `CURLOPT_HTTP_VERSION` parameter which will make cURL try to make an HTTP/2.0 request. After that you'll have to check the Headers from the request to check if the server does indeed support HTTP/2.0.

Example:

```
$url = "https://google.com";
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt_array($ch, [
    CURLOPT_URL            => $url,
    CURLOPT_HEADER         => true,
    CURLOPT_NOBODY         => true,
    CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,
    CURLOPT_HTTP_VERSION   => CURL_HTTP_VERSION_2_0, // cURL will attempt to make an HTTP/2.0 request (can downgrade to HTTP/1.1)
]);
$response = curl_exec($ch);
```

Now you'll need to check if cURL did indeed make an HTTP/2.0 request:

```
if ($response !== false && strpos($response, "HTTP/2.0") === 0) {
    echo "Server of the URL has HTTP/2.0 support."; // yay!
} elseif ($response !== false) {
    echo "Server of the URL has no HTTP/2.0 support."; // nope!
} else {
    echo curl_error($ch); // something else happened causing the request to fail
}
curl_close($ch);
```

Comment: pay attention, this URL (google.com) is answering by "HTTP/2"  (without point-zero), so crop it from strpos

Comment: @djdance Thanks for letting me know! I have updated the answer to reflect this and changes in the latest PHP versions, as you can now use `curl_getinfo()` to check the HTTP version the request used.

Comment: You are a star. all of a sudden none of the API request for the API key in the header ere being recognised, so after reading your post, I realised we were checking for API key with upper case, so revised my code to check for both and worked again. A+++